# Write CSV to HDFS from stream with pyarrow upload

Tags: pandas, csv, hdfs, pyarrow

I am trying to save a Pandas DataFrame to HDFS in CSV format using pyarrow upload method, but the CSV file saved is empty. The code example can be found below.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3]})
buf = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(buf)
hdfs = pa.hdfs.connect()
hdfs.upload("path/to/hdfs/test.csv", buf)
```

When I check the contents of test.csv on HDFS it is empty. What did I do wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `buf.seek(0)` before uploading.

Basically you need to rewind to the begining of the buffer otherwise hdfs thinks there's nothing to upload:

```
>>> buf.read()
''
>>> buf.seek(0)
0
>>> buf.read()
',x\n0,1\n1,2\n2,3\n'
>>> buf.read()
''
```

Comment: I tried to add buf.seek(0) but still end up with an empty CSV file